# Incorrect size of flex child with an image

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a similar case in my project:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }

    img {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/200x600">
      </div>
      <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have fixed width container (`.container`) that sets the height of its children to match its own height (due to `align-items: stretch;` by default). In one of those containers, I have an image (`<img>`) that I want to be the same height as its parent (`.image-wrapper`) while maintaining proportions. In the demo, that happens, but the `.image-wrapper` width is not updated. At least not always...

Sometimes, the image appears like this (**incorrect**):

[image: incorrect sizing]

...and sometimes, it appears like this (**correct**):

[image]

I think it has to do with the browser not updating the width of `.image-wrapper`. In the incorrect scenario, it has a width of `200` (the placeholder image's original size), but after the image is resized down to 100x300 (due to its `height: 100%` and its parent being `300px` while having a natural size of 200x600) the parent's width is not updated to reflect that. It should change from `200` to `100`, the image's now resized value.

One weird thing is that if the size is incorrect and you add `width: 100%` to `.image-wrapper` in the inspector and then remove it, its width is refreshed and is now displayed correctly.

If you download the snippet and open it in your browser, you should see that the image is displayed incorrectly until you open DevTools and disable cache. After that (because the image takes some time to load I guess), the width is set correctly upon refreshing.

This happens on latest Chrome, Firefox and IE11 on Windows 10. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/rh53sydu/) too.

Why does that happen? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you don't specify explicitly the size of the image; notably, this is a [known bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625560).

You can either:

1. Specify that in either the HTML `width` attribute, or the CSS `width` property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }

    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100px; /* 1st solution: you should use fixed width when using CSS */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/200x600" width="100"> <!-- 2nd solution -->
      </div>
      <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Use JavaScript to set the HTML width attribute to the actual image size at runtime:

```js
// Give your image a proper ID
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');

  // This sets the image's HTML width element
  // Notice the self-assignment
  img.width = img.width;
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/200x600" id='img' />
      </div>
      <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's one solution, yes, but I intentionally avoid setting a fixed width on the image. In my use case, it comes from a CMS and can have any width. I don't want to squash it. I want it to fit in its parent

Answer (score 0):

As is, apparently this is a known bug in Chrome, but to my confusion I am also experiencing this in Firefox...

There is 2 solutions to this:

1)

```
img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px; /* Set a specific width to your image */
}
```

2) Apparently removing the `image-wrapper` div also solves this problem immediately.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-basis: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
         <img src="https://placehold.co/200x600">
         <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```